# yaml-cpp cross-platform building, how to build arm in x86 ubuntu vm

Tags: c++, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, yaml-cpp

I am making a software, which used yaml-cpp to laod parameter. Now, I have to release to Raspberry pie. So i have to cross compiling to arm.

Usually, I have added arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc & arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ for this. And for other software, it could be used naturally. The code I used is showing below:

```
# 64 bit cross compiling
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
```

But when I add yaml-cpp, it was not work anymore. The ouput which is shwoing below is revolving.

```
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
[cmake] Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
[cmake] The following variables have changed:
[cmake] CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /usr/bin/g++
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done
```

And it runs normally wihtout 64 bit cross compiling.

The `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(RTUINS VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

# 64 bit cross compiling
# SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
# SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
# SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
# SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

file(GLOB CONFIG_RESOURSES "config/*.h" "config/*.cpp")
file(GLOB TIMER_RESOURCES "timer/*.h" "timer/*.cpp")
file(GLOB COMMUNICATION_RESOURCES "communication/*.h" "communication/*.cpp")
file(GLOB GENERAL_RESOURCES "general/*.h" "general/*.cpp")
file(GLOB DATAIO_RESOURSES "dataio/*.h" "dataio/*.cpp")
file(GLOB FILEIO_RESOURSES "fileio/*.h" "fileio/*.cpp")
file(GLOB TOOL_RESOURSES "tool/*.h" "tool/*.cpp" "tool/*.hpp")
file(GLOB ALIGNMENT_RESOURSES "alignment/*.h" "alignment/*.cpp")
file(GLOB CORE_RESOURSES "core/*.h" "core/*.cpp")

add_executable(RTUINS 
    ${CONFIG_RESOURSES}
    ${TIMER_RESOURCES} 
    ${COMMUNICATION_RESOURCES}
    ${DATAIO_RESOURSES}
    ${FILEIO_RESOURSES}
    ${TOOL_RESOURSES}
    ${GENERAL_RESOURCES}
    ${ALIGNMENT_RESOURSES}
    ${CORE_RESOURSES}
    main.cpp)

# Eigen3
include_directories(thirdparty/eigen-3.4.0)

# yaml
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/yaml-cpp-0.8.0)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} yaml-cpp)
```

The file tree is showing below:

```
├── alignment
│   ├── alignment.cpp
│   ├── alignment.h
│   ├── alignmentthread.cpp
│   └── alignmentthread.h
├── bin
│   ├── parse
│   ├── read
│   ├── RTUINS
│   └── sandbox
├── build
│   ├── build.ninja
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.22.1
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── cmake.verify_globs
│   │   ├── RTUINS.dir
│   │   ├── rules.ninja
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   └── VerifyGlobs.cmake
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── compile_commands.json
│   ├── CPackConfig.cmake
│   ├── CPackSourceConfig.cmake
│   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   ├── DartConfiguration.tcl
│   ├── Testing
│   │   ├── 20240324-0803
│   │   ├── TAG
│   │   └── Temporary
│   └── thirdparty
│       └── yaml-cpp-0.8.0
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── communication
│   ├── serial_communication.cpp
│   ├── serial_communication.h
│   ├── serial_driver.cpp
│   └── serial_driver.h
├── config
│   ├── defineconfig.h
│   ├── yamlconfig.cpp
│   └── yamlconfig.h
├── core
│   ├── ekf.cpp
│   ├── ekf.h
│   ├── insmech.cpp
│   ├── insmech.h
│   ├── instypedef.h
│   ├── integrated.cpp
│   ├── integrated.h
│   ├── processthread.cpp
│   ├── processthread.h
│   └── systeminfo.h
├── dataio
│   ├── commandmonitor.cpp
│   ├── commandmonitor.h
│   ├── dataverify.cpp
│   ├── dataverify.h
│   ├── dvlloader.cpp
│   ├── dvlloader.h
│   ├── imuloader.cpp
│   ├── imuloader.h
│   ├── navressender.cpp
│   └── navressender.h
├── doc
│   ├── coreflow.drawio
│   ├── framework.xmind
│   └── systemflow.drawio
├── fileio
│   ├── filebase.h
│   ├── filesaver.cpp
│   ├── filesaver.h
│   ├── navfilethread.cpp
│   ├── navfilethread.h
│   ├── savefilethread.cpp
│   └── savefilethread.h
├── general
│   ├── angle.h
│   ├── earth.h
│   ├── rotation.h
│   └── typedef.h
├── lib
│   └── libyaml-cpp.a
├── main.cpp
├── README.md
├── saveddata
│   ├── dvldata20240321_201713.dat
│   ├── HostComputer.py
│   ├── imudata20240321_201713.dat
│   ├── navdata20240321_201713.dat
│   ├── navdata20240323_205931.dat
│   ├── res1
│   │   ├── dvldata20240321_112553.dat
│   │   ├── imudata20240321_112553.dat
│   │   └── navdata20240321_112553.dat
│   └── showdata.py
├── thirdparty
│   ├── eigen-3.4.0
│   │   ├── bench
│   │   ├── blas
│   │   ├── ci
│   │   ├── cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── COPYING.APACHE
│   │   ├── COPYING.BSD
│   │   ├── COPYING.GPL
│   │   ├── COPYING.LGPL
│   │   ├── COPYING.MINPACK
│   │   ├── COPYING.MPL2
│   │   ├── COPYING.README
│   │   ├── CTestConfig.cmake
│   │   ├── CTestCustom.cmake.in
│   │   ├── debug
│   │   ├── demos
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   ├── Eigen
│   │   ├── eigen3.pc.in
│   │   ├── failtest
│   │   ├── INSTALL
│   │   ├── lapack
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
│   │   ├── test
│   │   └── unsupported
│   └── yaml-cpp-0.8.0
│       ├── BUILD.bazel
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── cmake_uninstall.cmake.in
│       ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│       ├── docs
│       ├── include
│       ├── install.txt
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── SECURITY.md
│       ├── src
│       ├── test
│       ├── util
│       ├── WORKSPACE
│       ├── yaml-cpp-config.cmake.in
│       └── yaml-cpp.pc.in
├── timer
│   ├── timebase.cpp
│   ├── timebase.h
│   ├── timeouthandler.cpp
│   ├── timeouthandler.h
│   ├── timestamp.cpp
│   └── timestamp.h
└── tool
    ├── ColorParse.cpp
    ├── ColorParse.h
    ├── MBUtils.cpp
    ├── MBUtils.h
    └── SafeQueue.hpp
```

I tried everyting I could. Please help me, thanks.

add corss compiling and yaml-cpp

```
# 64 bit cross compiling
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
```

The configure ouput which is shwoing below is revolving.

```
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
[cmake] Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
[cmake] The following variables have changed:
[cmake] CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /usr/bin/g++
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done
```